# How to transfer data from local file system (linux) to a Hadoop Cluster made on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: linux, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hdfs

I am a beginner in ***Hadoop***, I made a Hadoop Cluster (one master and two slaves) on ***Google Cloud Platform***.

I accessed the master of the cluster using from the local file system **(Linux)**: `ssh -i key key@public_ip_of_master`

Then I did `sudo su -`  inside the cluster because Hadoop functions **only** appears while being root.

Then I initiated the HDFS using `start-dfs.sh`  and `start-all.sh`

**Now the problem** is that I want to tranfer files *from* **the local Linux file system** *to* **the Hadoop Cluster** and *vice versa* using the following command **(inserting the command inside the cluster while being root)**:

```
root@master:~# hdfs dfs -put   /home/abas1/Desktop/chromFa.tar.gz     /Hadoop_File
```

The **problem is** that the local path which is: `/home/abas1/Desktop/chromFa.tar.gz` **is never recognized**  and I can not seem to know what to do.

I am sure I am missing something trivial but I do not know what it is. I have to use either `-copyFromLocal` or `-put`.

Comment: Do you use dataproc?

Comment: No... Just Hadoop... I don't know how to use dataproc... Would you tell me how would it help please? Thanks

Comment: Dataproc is a managed hadoop cluster. I think you should start by using it and then you will be able to transfer easily files.

Comment: 1) make sure that you have permissions on the file and sorce file and target folder exists
2) usually hdfs data is stored under hdfs user so you need to do sudo under hdfs user
3) check that hdfs service is up and running. Connect to name node and run -ls on it
4) in gcp use dataproc for managed hadoop clusters
5) more details https://www.udemy.com/course/cca-131-cloudera-certified-hadoop-and-spark-administrator/learn/lecture/13393334#overview

Answer (score 1):

> local path is never recognized

That is not a Hadoop problem, then. You are on the `master` node (over SSH), as the `root` user. There is a `/root` folder with files, and probably no `/home/abas1`.

In other words, run `ls -l /home`, and you see what local files are available.

To get files to the `master` server to upload from *that terminal session*, you will want to SCP files first to there from a different machine.

1. Exit the SSH session
2. `scp -i key root@master-ip home/abas1/Desktop/chromFa.tar.gz /tmp`
3. `ssh -i key root@master-ip`
4. **Then** you can do this

```
hdfs mkdir /Hadoop_File
ls -l /tmp | grep chromFa  # for example, to check file
hdfs -put /tmp/chromFa.tar.gz /Hadoop_file/
```

> Hadoop functions only appears while being root.

Please do not use `root` for interacting with Hadoop services. Create unique user accounts for HDFS, YARN, Zookeeper, etc. with restricted permissions like you would for any other Unix process.

Using DataProc will do this... And you can still SSH to it, so you should really considering using it instead of manual GCE cluster.